# How to suppress file output from aws s3 ls?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using the aws cli to summarize the number of files and the total size of an s3 bucket using the following command ([documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)):

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

This command gives me the following output:

```
2013-09-02 21:37:53   10 Bytes a.txt
2013-09-02 21:37:53  2.9 MiB foo.zip
2013-09-02 21:32:57   23 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/a
2013-09-02 21:32:58   41 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/b
2013-09-02 21:32:57  281 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/c
2013-09-02 21:32:57   73 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/d
2013-09-02 21:32:57  452 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/e
2013-09-02 21:32:57  896 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/bar
2013-09-02 21:32:57  189 Bytes foo/bar/.baz/hooks/foo
2013-09-02 21:32:57  398 Bytes z.txt

Total Objects: 10
   Total Size: 2.9 MiB
```

However, I'm only after the `Total Objects` and `Total Size` output, e.g.:

```
Total Objects: 10
   Total Size: 2.9 MiB
```

How can I only display the `Total Objects` and `Total Size` while suppressing/hiding the rest?

Comment: `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize | tail -2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) to show the last few lines or [grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to filter the output based on the "Total" keyword at the beginning of the line (optionally with the extra whitespace), like:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize|tail -n2
```

Or

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize|grep -e '^\s*Total'
```